# SQL Query to Group By and Concat rows

Tags: sql, ms-access

Hi I have the following table:

```
Doc      |  code    | Qty | Next
5211386  |  91992   |  1  | 52183
5211386  |  91992   |  1  | 52182
```

I trying to figure out a way to group the records by the first two colums, sum the third and concat the last column to obtain something like:

```
Doc      |  code    | Qty | Next
5211386  |  91992   |  2  | 52183-52182
```

Any help?

Comment: When you say "MS SQL", do you mean Microsoft SQL Server? If so, why the `ms-access` tag? If you meant MS Access, though, then please don't call it "MS SQL", that is *very* confusing. (If this question is about SQL Server, please retag it, use the `sql-server` tag instead of `ms-access`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for a group_concat like function found in MySQL. [Check out Allen Browne's solution](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html)

```
SELECT Doc, code, Sum(Qty), ConcatRelated("[Next]","TableName",,,"-") as [Next]
FROM TableName
GROUP BY Doc, code
```

Comment: Hi it worked! I just needed to add the third parameter:
"Doc = " & [Doc] & " AND code = " & [code]
Thanks!